# Dataframe Column generation based on constraint

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe having :

```
B_Date   C_b
02/08/2019  2
02/08/2019  1
02/08/2019  1
02/08/2019  1 
02/08/2019  3
02/08/2019  3
02/08/2019  2
02/08/2019  2
02/08/2019  2
02/08/2019  1
02/08/2019  4
02/08/2019  3
02/08/2019  4
02/08/2019  2
02/08/2019  4
02/08/2019  3
02/08/2019  4
02/08/2019  4
02/08/2019  4
03/08/2019  3
03/08/2019  1
```

I want to create a new column i_found such that for a particular date, if sum of C_b is greater than 5000, it should put 4 otherwise 5 in all the entries.

**Expected Output**

```
     B_Date    C_b  i_found
    02/08/2019  2    5
    02/08/2019  1    5
    02/08/2019  1    5
    02/08/2019  1    5
    02/08/2019  3    5
```

Note that this is just the sample entry and total won't reach 5000 but the dataframe has a total of 30k entries, where c_b reaches 5000. Can anyone help with the same.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do a `merge` to obtain the groupby sum, then assign the new values:

```
s = df.merge(df.groupby("B_Date").sum().reset_index(),on="B_Date",how="left",suffixes=("_old","_new"))
s["i_found"] = np.where(s["C_b_new"]>5000, 4, 5)

print (s.drop("C_b_new", axis=1))
#
        B_Date  C_b_old  i_found
0   02/08/2019        2        5
1   02/08/2019        1        5
2   02/08/2019        1        5
3   02/08/2019        1        5
4   02/08/2019        3        5
5   02/08/2019        3        5
6   02/08/2019        2        5
7   02/08/2019        2        5
8   02/08/2019        2        5
9   02/08/2019        1        5
10  02/08/2019        4        5
11  02/08/2019        3        5
12  02/08/2019        4        5
13  02/08/2019        2        5
14  02/08/2019        4        5
15  02/08/2019        3        5
16  02/08/2019        4        5
17  02/08/2019        4        5
18  02/08/2019        4        5
19  03/08/2019        3        5
20  03/08/2019        1        5
```